# Java .split() Array out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, split

I keep getting this Array out of bounds error for the following code.

brock.txt = reflection program, routine, Arrow, snake game,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = "brock.txt";
    String line; 
    String [] cities = {};
    int x = 0;
    try {

    BufferedReader eshread = new BufferedReader( new FileReader (filename));
        line = "";

        while ((line = eshread.readLine()) != null ) {
        String[] store = line.split(",");
        System.out.println(store[0]);
        System.out.println(store[1]);
        System.out.println(store[2]);
        cities[x] = store[2];            //< keep getting an error here
        x++;
        }//end while loop
        eshread.close();
        }//end try
    catch(IOException iox) {
    System.out.println("failiure");
    }//end catch
```

Comment: `String [] cities = {}` that's the reason

Answer (score 0):

`String [] cities = {}` will make the array size to 0,when `x` is greater than `0` the error will occur,that's the reason,so you need to make `cities` a fixed size at first or use `List` to do it

Answer (score 0):

You Must define the size of cities or use a list .

Answer (score 0):

You initialized `cities` with an empty array(`{}`), which means it has a length of 0(not an null, but an empty array). By using `cities[0]` you are expecting it has at least one element, which is not true.

To fix this, use an `ArrayList<String>` instead of a String array.

Answer (score 0):

In agreement with the other comments. The issue is with the size of *cities* array which is being set to 0 and hence the issue for array out of bounds. 
I tried the following code and it works if you want to work with a String array.
Else an ***ArrayList*** is a better solution if the size is not defined.

```
    String [] cities = new String[10];
```